# Excel evaluation tree bug? Nested call to addin function called 20,000 times

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-addins

Excel 2003, Windows XP SP3:

We have a number of Excel users who work with very large, complex Excel workbooks.  A typical workbook may have 60+ worksheets and be upwards of 70MB in size.  We have an .xll addin that we produce and is used throughout these spreadsheets.  We have extensive debugging and logging capabilities with our addin.

We have noticed some extremely odd and erratic behaviour which we have been unable to reproduce consistently.  I describe here a typical manifestation of the problem.

One of the ranges of one spreadsheet has a formula array that involves nested calls to functions, both Excel ss functions and our own addin functions.  A formula might look something like:

```
{=IF(cndtn,AddinFcn1(rng,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($A2549,rng2,col,0)),AddinFcn2(param)),-1)}
```

where AddinFcn1 and AddinFcn2 are registered functions within our addin.  We can monitor the number of times Excel calls in to each of our addin functions, and match all calls to the cell or range evaluation that causes the call.  If we load the addin and workbook in a clean Excel, and then calculate the workbook ("F9"), the calculation may complete fine the first, second, maybe even 10 times, and we can see a single call to both AddinFcn2 and AddinFcn1 stemming from the evaluation of the range containing the above formula.  But *some* times, things begin to go crazy: on the third "F9", the inner AddinFcn2 may suddenly get called by excel 19 times, and then on the 4th "F9", the inner AddinFcn2 gets called 20,000 times.  Or maybe everything is fine until the 10th "F9" when suddenly the inner AddinFcn2 gets called 19,000 times during the evaluation of the range.  Oddly, the outer function AddinFcn1 still gets invoked only once.

There seems to be no rhyme or reason to when this happens, or how many times the function gets called.  The data coming in to the call, indeed the data everywhere in the spreadsheet, is the same each F9  - nothing changes from one calculation to the next.

Has anyone seen similar behaviour?  Does anyone have any guess as to what might cause Excel to (unnecessarily) recompute an inner function call tens, even hundreds of thousands of times?

Comment: Since you are not able to reproduce the issue and in the absence of any code , my guess is as good as yours :) Possibly the workbook which is causing this problem has a `Worksheet_Change` event where `Application.EnableEvents` is not set to `false`, resulting in an endless kind of loop?

Comment: That's a good guess.  But, a number of things argue against that: (1) it's not endless - 20,000 is big, but not infinite; (2) I can't find any `Worksheet_Change` code in any of the VBA; (3) I think that would result in multiple (infinite) evaluations of the whole range or cell, which we are **not** seeing - `AddinFcn1` is only called once.

Comment: We can reproduce it, just not consistently.  It happens often, but not in any _predictable_ way.